# Configuration in MPLABX compared to MikroC Pro

Tags: pic, microchip, mplabx

I need to modify a C code of an PIC18F4550. I want to use the MPLAB X IDE to do the job because I'm more familiar with it. However, the code that I need to modify is accompanied by an introduction tutorial of programming using the MikroC-Pro. In the tutorial, when it was explaining how to creat a project, it edited the project. So, I noticed a difference between the two IDEs. The MikroC asks for a lot more information like frequency, Oscilator etc...  I didn't find how to make a similar configuration in the MPLAB X's project.

I would like to know, why MPLAB X did not ask this information ? Will I need to add this information in my code, I mean , I will need to type it in the C file using MPLABX ?

Below is the print-screen of the information availabe to edit the project in the MikroC.

[image]

Comment: You can put this information in with either the configuration bits it memory views or with the code configurator. These are two different tools that set the configuration registers.

Comment: @vini_i I think the MCC to the model PIC18F4550 is not available. So I follow your recommendation and found this tutorial in this website: http://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:view-and-set-configuration-bits so, I generate the code, save it to its own file and add it to my project. I think it will do the job.

Comment: Glad I could help. That should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mplab X install a plugin called "MPLAB Code Configurator" AKA MCC. It allows to configure clock, remappable pins, peripherals, etc. It also generates IO routines for the peripherals with errata workarounds already implemented :-).

Comment: I intalled it following the tutorial video of installation. When I tried to use it, I was informed that the project's device is not supported by the currently loaded libraries. So, I downloaded the pic10-pic12-pic16-pic18_v1.76.0.jar and installed it following this document: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/release_notes_pic10_pic12_pic16_pic18_v1_65_2.pdf . But still have the same message of warning : "The project's device is not supported by the currently loaded libraries..." I think it is not supported yet...

Comment: You're correct. I tried to make a project with  PIC18F4550 and got the same result, probably because the part is very old. Still, MCC is the best way to configure current PICs.